# Automatic scoll down on document refresh (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since VS Code can auto-refresh a document when it is changed from outside, I would like to scroll down to the last line automatically.
I'm sure this feature worked on previous versions but now I found no entry in settings to enable it.

It is helpful in order to monitor a log file while been write.

Is there any way to enable this feature?

Comment: Is there any update on this? Sublime has such a feature, but Sublime doesn't refresh when out of focus. Code refreshes when out of focus, but doesn't autoscroll to EOF.

Comment: The only tool I found in order to do this is notepad++. It has an interesting "monitoring" option (view > monitoring). If enabled, this should autore-fresh (and scroll to EOF).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So I created a VS Code extension for this, it's called [autoscrolldown](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=foxx1337.autoscrolldown).

Building the world's most expensive `tail -f`!

Comment: I works fine. Plus, the "autoscrolldown.onlyWhenAtEnd"-option is the cherry on the cake.

Comment: We need to enable the "Also autoscroll active" to monitor it live following the tail, also disable the "only when at end" option. This is allowing live monitoring with tail -f like *ix systems.

Answer (score 7):

[Auto Scroll](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pejmannikram.vscode-auto-scroll) extension does this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the keybinding to scroll to the bottom of the file:

```
{
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.scrollToBottom",
  "key": "ctrl+end",
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>End</kbd>

I don't see any other way to have the scrolling be automatic when a file refreshes.

Comment: What if I need to monitor a log file while other programs write it?
I just cannot stay focused on the editor for each line been written. 
Other editors allow me to autorefresh and autoscoll to the end (vs code too in the past)

Comment: It appears vscode preserves the previous scroll position on re-opening or refreshing a file.  I suppose that is what most people would want.  If you don't get a better answer, you should file a request to have a setting to have the scroll position updated to where new edits have been made upon reopen or refresh.  There might be significant support for that.